# Insert multiple rows when range contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a macro to run through a column of data and insert a row for every instance it counts a "," so for example it would insert another 3 rows above Joanne

[image]

I currently have this code below but it doesn't work and im not sure im on the right track for it as I think it is looking for "," to only be the only contents in the cell? Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub InsertRow()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("E2:E9999")
    If cell.Value = "," Then
        cell.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Insert As Many Rows As There Are Commas

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub InsertCommaRows()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim cString As String
    Dim CommasCount As Long
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = lRow - 1 To 2 Step -1
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(r, "E").Address(0, 0)
        cString = CStr(ws.Cells(r, "E").Value)
        CommasCount = Len(cString) - Len(Replace(cString, ",", ""))
        If CommasCount > 0 Then
            ws.Cells(r + 1, "E").Resize(CommasCount).EntireRow _
                .Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Comma-rows inserted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code counts the commas then inserts the same number of rows immediately below the current cell.

```
Sub InsertRow()
Dim cell As Range
Dim iCommas As Integer
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E9999")
    iCommas = Len(cell.Value) - Len(Replace(cell.Value, ",", ""))
    If iCommas > 0 Then
        cell.Offset(1).Resize(iCommas).EntireRow.Insert xlDown
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```